# Javascript local variables . How to reference in cicle

Tags: javascript, oop, variables, object

This is what i do to reference global variables in a cycle.

```
 _.forEach(myTableName.detailsObjects, function (o, key) {

                    if (window[o] && window[o].serverSideProcessing == true) {
                        window[o].prepareData(data, false);
                        window[o].setDML(data, false);
```

But what if they are local variables.

o.prepareData and o.setDml dont work.
Thanks

Comment: Inside the function, local variables can be referenced using `this['variableName']`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is the exact problem you have, but it works with local variables too.
Here are two versions of code, first is pure js using `Array.forEach` and second uses underscore's `_.forEach`.

```js
myTableName = {
    "detailsObjects": [
        {"id":1, "prepareData":true}, 
        {"id":2, "prepareData":false}
    ]
}

myTableName.detailsObjects.forEach(function(o, key) {
    alert('Result: ' + o.id + ': ' + o.prepareData + ' key: ' + key); 
})


_.forEach(myTableName.detailsObjects, function(o, key) {
    alert('Underscore Result: ' + o.id + ': ' + o.prepareData + ' key: ' + key); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```